# Use tx_form in custom Extension

Tags: forms, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x, view-helpers

I want to use the EXT:form to include a form in my extension.
In the detail-page is a link to the formAction. The recipients dependents on a dataset (detailView)

I hope I got it right.
I can create my own formular with my own factoryclass and render this form in my extension in Fluid with the viewhelper `formvh:render` , as described in the documentation.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us//I/ApiReference/Index.html#factoryclass

If I do this like in the example, the form will render in my Extension.
But if I try to send the data to the next step, then this should be done via my action "index" (as in the documentation) or "perform".
And i get the error
The action "perform" (controller "Job") is not allowed by this plugin
Do I have to create these actions in my own controller or can I leave the whole thing to Ext:form?

Same problem if i use

```
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Forms/SimpleContactForm.yaml" />
```

Do i have to register somthing or use a typoscript implementation?